# Check the id and classes

Tags: jquery

I have this statement:

```
$(#my-name.class-c1.class-c2).length
```

is it the following?

id:my-name
class: class-c1
class: class-c2

Based on the statement I would like to understand if there are 2 classes to the element to take the length.

Comment: you forgot to add quotes! ```$("#my-name.class-c1.class-c2").length```

Comment: If you habe an ID, which has to be unique in the document, you don't need classes to address the element and remember the quotes.

Comment: ID's must be unique! and so it's enough you select the element only by ID.
```$("#my-name")``` more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Comment: @Joerg unless you're using this to determine if the element has the class(es)  (in which case, use `.is` or `.filter`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put selector in quotes like below

```
var len = $("#my-name.class-c1.class-c2").length;
alert(len);
```

This will give you count of element with `id=my-name` and having classes `class-c1 class-c2`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to put quotes around the selector:

```
$('#my-name.class-c1.class-c2').length
```

Having said that, this selector will select the element which has the ID "my-name" *and* has both the "class-c1" and "class-c2" classes as well.

You could argue that this is redundant since the ID should be unique, there should not be any other element in the page with the my-name ID so $('#my-name') should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
var classList =$('#divId').attr('class').split(/\s+/);
$.each( classList, function(index, item){
    if (item === 'someClass') {
       //do something
    }
});
```

You can use jquery each function

Comment: Or you could use [jquery is](https://api.jquery.com/is/) which does exactly this for you

Answer (score 1):

The selector:

```
$("#my-name.class-c1.class-c2")
```

will match the single node/tag with the specified classes, eg:

```
<div id='my-name' class='class-c1 class-c2'></div>
```

(assuming a div, could be any element)

As there are no spaces or other selector separators in the selector, then they must all apply to the same element, if you had this:

```
<div id='my-name' class='class-c1'></div>
```

then the selector would not find it.

It looks like you're using this to determine if an element has a specific class, in this case you can change the code to a slightly less confusing (based on opinion ofc):

```
if ($("#my-name").is(".class-c1"))
if ($("#my-name").is(".class-c1.class-c2"))
```

More info on `is` in the [jquery docs](https://api.jquery.com/is/)